# Kaomoji search engine

Tags: gratis, chat, search-engine, unicode

[Kaomoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon#Japanese_style) is a powerful way to add expressiveness to characters-only conversations:

```
(*_*)   ^_^'       m(__)m    (^▽^)ノ    （＾。＾@）／    ヽ(^^)(^^)ノ♪    ＿|￣|○
＼(^0^)人(^0^)／    (゜゜)(。。)    (≧へ≦)    (-_-ﾒ)    （*｀Д´）    (・∀・)つ目
```

Most kaomojis include unusual characters, and are hard to remember/type. Japanese mobile devices keyboards include them, classified in categories.

I am looking for a way to quickly find the relevant kaomoji for given keywords.
For instance a query for `give tea happy` would return `(・∀・)つ目` and similar ones.
A bit similar to http://giphy.com except Giphy returns GIFs instead of kaomojis.

Requirements:

- It could be an Android app, a third-party web tool, a web service API, or a Linux-compatible desktop program
- Free to use
- The UI and keywords can be in any language

Comment: Here is an app: http://japaneseemoticons.me/#text-3 though it doesnt support searching by keyword as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've found so far:

- [Linux cmdline tool](https://github.com/cspeterson/splatmoji)
- [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/kaomojie/)

Comment: Could you please add details and screenshots for each? Ideally as an answer per solution, so that both can be upvoted independently. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some web applications:

https://emojicombos.com/ (may give kaomojis or just emojis depending on query)

https://asciilib.iansinnott.com/ (open source)

Comment: It would help if you expressed more information about them. rather than a list that could be obtained by googling.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: emojicombos does not give kaomojis, it only gives emojis, right?
On the other side, asciilib.iansinnott.com looks like what the question asks for, great find! Could you please add a screenshot of it, explain briefly in words how it works, and remove the first link? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andrew: That's why you should post explanations and screenshots: https://emojidb.org/give-tea-happy-emojis?user_typed_query=1&utm_source=user_search